# Cheapest unlocked 4G Android phone in the UK (October 2017)

Tags: android, mobile-phone

In the US I was able to buy a Tracfone for $20 *(4G Android)* - it's locked to the mobile carrier.

I would like to buy some super cheap 4G Android phone in the UK, preferably that is unlocked.

I'm talking about **£20 territory**, not £120 territory. Phone that will be used for projects, not for daily usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind it not being android the AEG M1220 is £11.95 and I think it has 4G. For android phones you're looking at about £50 and they don't even have 4G. If it's for projects look for older phones with broken screens/buttons on eBay as they'll likely be much cheaper since they cannot be used well as a phone.

Comment: I need to install some apps. It was $20 in the US... £50 is still reasonable / sensible.

Comment: @MichalStefanow simply go on Amazon and sort by lowest price and you'll find a few.

Comment: £45 https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=sr_nr_n_1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A356496011%2Ck%3Aandroid+4g&sort=price-asc-rank&keywords=android+4g&ie=UTF8&qid=1508174619&rnid=1642204031